# asp.net web services : How can I answer before completing the task

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I need to make a web service that will implement Delete/Add.Since these operations require other time-consuming operations, the web service should answer immediately ( something like "OK, I'll do it" ) and do the tasks afterwards. The program that calls the web service doesn't need to know if the operation succeeded, it just needs to give the command and forget about it.
Can this be implemented in ASP.NET web services and how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created a proxy for the webservice from wsdl then it should contain async methods. These will have names that start with "begin" and "end".  These can be used to make an asynchronous call to the Web service. Try  search Google for the rest.

Comment: I don't like asynchronous call,I need the web service to respond and then continue its work.

Comment: In the method of the Web service start your processing on a new thread, then return out of the web service.